# getting an unexpected space in perl output

Tags: regex, perl

i am trying to execute the following perl script .

```
$var = "\$53:\$\?\$\?\$\?  \$\=BAbc \$\? \$53: \$ hjk"
$var =~ s/(\$\=B)/FLAGB/;
$var =~ s/(?<=\$53:).*?(?=.[^\$\?\s])//
$var =~ s/(FLAGB)/\$\=B/;
print "\n$var";
```

the output which i am getting is

```
$53: $=BAbc $? $53: $ hjkb
```

what i am trying to do is to remove all $ and/or ? and/or spaces after `$53`: until the first character(other than $ or ? or space) is encountered and preserve if `$=B` (i am replacing it with `FLAGB` before the substitute operation)

Now i am not able to find why an extra space is appearing in the output after `$53`:

```
$53: $=BAbc $? $53: $ hjkb
```

forgive my ignorance if the issue is something silly, i am new to perl.

Comment: Side note; have fun in future maintenance of that piece of code. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think

```
s/(?<=\$53:).*?(?=.[^\$\?\s])//
```

should be without dot:

```
s/(?<=\$53:).*?(?=[^\$\?\s])//
```

That one kept the space before the h as look-ahead.

Answer (score 2):

The pragmatic thing to do would be to get rid of the spaces.

```
$var =~ s/(?<=:)\s//g;
```

Comment: yes that can be done. But i am still not sure why an extra space is appearing at the start of $53: